IDAPython: error executing init.py
When I open Ida Pro 8.3 I see an error message
IDAPython: error executing init.py:
No module named imp
Refer to the message window to see the full error log.
i have python 3.12.3 and i ran as adminitrator the idapyswitch.exe and the same error appear

This problem is caused by python/3/ida_idaapi.py a Python script that comes with IDA.
In IDA 8.4 this file has been updated. It does no longer contain import imp, thus it should work with Python 3.12.

i found the problem, in that file from import imp was needed to write import importlib and it works

Another way of solving this is:
in browser, open
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/imp.py
then in your python main directory, C:\Users<your name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312 (or where you installed python), go to Lib folder and create imp.py folder. Then copy code from github. That's it, should work now.

Try using python 3.11 instead,i got this issue before and reverting back to python 3.11 somehow did the trick

If the imp module will miss in the python 3.13 or newer versions, what should I do because I don`t want to stay on 3.11 only because I have this error. Or I can install a second version of python and chose to use the 3.11 for ida and the other version for myself?

Yeah, you can still use both so there should be no problem since for each python ver has different path and they wont interfere with each other.
